# Use a non-Magento page as homepage

Tags: magento-1.7, redirect, htaccess

As my webshop homepage I want to show a statis html page `index.html`. How can I accomplish this with .htaccess rewrites?

All other pages are from the Magento installation.

```
event:


    example.com  redirect to example.com/index.html (which is not an magento page)
    example.com/index.php  redirect to example.com/index.html (which is not an magento page)

but  i want to show other magento pages ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Find the `DirectoryIndex` in your root .htaccess file.

```
############################################
## default index file

DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

Write the index.html prior to index.php so when you open your site url first it will open the index.html page.